# The member with identity 'IdentitySample.Models.Team_Players' does not exist in the metadata collection. Parameter name: identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

The objective that I'm trying to achieve is that you have a Team which has many Players (ApplicationUsers), and you have Players (ApplicationUsers) which can potentially have many Teams. (Currently I am just focused on assigning one team).

I am receiving the error (in the title of this question) upon creation of a new user (code is below). After successfully creating a new user the code will call:

```
CreateAsync(user, userViewModel.Password);
```

which is where it fails.

The error that I am receiving seems to be related to Entity Framework and the instructions it's sending to SQL (I have a local instance of SQL Express configured in the Connection String). I have searched StackOverflow for this error and there do seem to be a lot of posts, but I can't seem to find an answer that relates to this circumstance - they all seem to reference SQL directly. Unfortunately I am new to .NET and am weak in EF and SQL which is why I am reaching out.

I believe the issue is something to do with the foreign key that EF is trying to establish between Teams and ApplicationUsers given the "IdentitySample.Models.*Team_Players*" part of the error.

I am working off of the .NET Identity 2.0 sample project, and have added some additional properties to the included **ApplicationUser** class which relate to a new class I added, "Team".

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here - db NOTE: Registration of claims from "IdentityExtensions.cs" class. See file.
        // These need to be added to the ViewModels and the Controllers to capture the data. See the "AccountViewModel.cs"
        // file, the "ManageViewModels.cs" and the "AccountController.cs" files, plus the views for corresponding changes.

        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("firstName", firstName));
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("lastName", lastName));
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("number", number.ToString()));

        return userIdentity;
    }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Hawks Number")]
    public int number { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Successful Logins")]
    public int successfulLogins { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Password Status")]
    public bool tempPassword { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        Teams = new List<Team>();
    }

}

public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Players { get; set; }

    public Team()
    {
        Players = new List<ApplicationUser>();
    }
}
```

I have two DbContexts, the included **ApplicationDbContext** along with one I added - **IdentityDB** - which inherits from the ApplicationDbContext class. In the IdentityDB context I have added the Team DbSet, "Teams".

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        // Set the database intializer which is run once during application start
        // This seeds the database with admin user credentials and admin role
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}

public class IdentityDB : ApplicationDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}
```

I am creating a user by creating an instance of a view model called RegistrationViewModel:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Assigned Team")]
    public string SelectedTeam { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Hawks Number")]
    public int number { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage= "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SelectListItem> Teams { get; set; }
    public RegisterViewModel()
    {
        Teams = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
}
```

in the UserAdminController:

```
    //
    // GET: /Users/Create
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
    {
        //Get the list of Roles
        ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(await RoleManager.Roles.ToListAsync(), "Name", "Name");
        //Get list of Teams
        IdentityDB _db = new IdentityDB();

        var teams = _db.Teams.Select(t => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = t.Name,
            Text = t.Name
        }).ToList();

        return View(new RegisterViewModel { Teams = teams });
    }

    //
    // POST: /Users/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(RegisterViewModel userViewModel, params string[] selectedRoles)
    {
        IdentityDB _db = new IdentityDB();

        Team userTeam = _db.Teams.First(x => x.Name == userViewModel.SelectedTeam);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = userViewModel.Email,
                Email = userViewModel.Email,
                firstName = userViewModel.firstName,
                lastName = userViewModel.lastName,
                number = userViewModel.number,
                successfulLogins = 0,
                tempPassword = true                    
            };

            user.Teams.Add(userTeam);

            var adminresult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, userViewModel.Password); // CODE FAILS HERE

            //Add User to the selected Roles 
            if (adminresult.Succeeded)
            {
                if (selectedRoles != null)
                {
                    var result = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, selectedRoles);
                    if (!result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
                        ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(await RoleManager.Roles.ToListAsync(), "Name", "Name");
                        return View();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", adminresult.Errors.First());
                ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(RoleManager.Roles, "Name", "Name");
                return View();

            }

    // Various email related activities that work fine and are unrelated to this error.
        }

        ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(RoleManager.Roles, "Name", "Name");

        return View();
    }
```

The definition of the CreateAsync method that the code fails at is:

```
[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(UserManager<,>.<CreateAsync>d__d))]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public virtual Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(TUser user, string password);
```

The SQL Express database does contain a table called "ApplicationUserTeams" with the 'TeamId' and 'ApplicationUser_Id' columns created, so it seems like EF is doing its job though something is failing along the way.

Steps taken to troubleshoot at this point include deleting the entire database and the migration folder in the project, then running the application again so it creates a fresh instance, along with a new "initial" migration. This did not have any effect on the issue. I really don't know where to go from here so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

**EDIT:** In working on an Index view for the "Team" controller, I noticed I am getting an error 'Invalid object name 'dbo.ApplicationUserTeams'. This was a result of iterating over the foreign key property "Players" which are of type Application User.

```
@model IEnumerable<IdentitySamplesTEST.Models.Team>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            @if (item.Players.Count == 0) @*ERROR OCCURS HERE*@
            {
                <td>
                    None.
                </td>
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var player in item.Players)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => player.firstName)
                    </td>
                }
            }
```

The table in the database is actually called **dbo.TeamApplicationUsers** - backwards to what EF seems to be looking. I have no idea what would cause this...

Comment: I'd update the nuget packages for entity framework to ensure they are the most up to date versions, delete the database and migrations again, create a new initial migration (as you already said) and then try it again.

Comment: Thanks @Coulton - I confirmed that EF is at its latest stable version, 6.1.3. Tried deleting the db and migrations again to no effect as yet.

Comment: How strange.  EF successfully scaffolds the new inital migration without any errors?

Comment: Seems to, yes. I have pasted the input/output from the console below:

Comment: PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName IdentityDB
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
Code First Migrations enabled for project IdentitySamplesTEST.
PM> Add-Migration Initial
Scaffolding migration 'Initial'.
The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your current Code First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the changes to your model when you scaffold the next migration. If you make additional changes to your model that you want to include in this migration, then you can re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration Initial' again.

Comment: I added a new paragraph to the main body of the question which may help in diagnosing the problem. EF seems to be looking for a table that is named differently to what it actually created for me...